# How does apache determine what directory to show from public_html?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, directory, symlink, apache-httpd

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have configured apache to serve from `~/public_html`. I am trying to serve some directory contents over http on LAN.

When I did the following:

```
ln -s ../Videos/android-internals-marakana/ android-internals-marakana
```

I was able to see the specified directory at localhost (in browser) with my public_html directory contents as follows:

```
k4rtik: public_html $ ls -l
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 k4rtik k4rtik   37 May 27 15:59 android-internals-marakana -> ../Videos/android-internals-marakana/
drwxrwxr-x 2 k4rtik k4rtik 4096 May 19 13:05 cgi-bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 k4rtik k4rtik 1406 May 19 12:20 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 k4rtik k4rtik  178 May 19 10:21 nindex.html
```

But when I similarly try creating a link to android documentation with

```
ln -s ../bin/android-sdk-linux/docs/ droid-docs
```

I get the symbolic link in directory listing but not at localhost in browser.

I have checked everything I could on my own - directory permissions, validity of the link, typing the dir name in the url directly (received **Forbidden** - You don't have permission to access /droid-docs on this server. there).

Any clue on what's going on and how to get this to work? Is it because `bin` folder is somewhat special as compared to other folders in my `home` directory?

Comment: What are the permissions of `~/bin/`, `~/bin/android-sdk-linux` and `~/bin/android-sdk-linux/docs/`

Comment: Damn, didn't think about that. There was just one problem with android-sdk-linux directory - rwxrwx---. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer...

Comment: Share your apache config please , at least <Directory XX> part

Comment: No drastic change from Ubuntu's default config. I have just set the directory root to ~/public_html as mentioned in the question. If you are really interested in that have a look at https://k4rtik.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/configuring-apache-for-developing-multiple-websites-under-ubuntu-linux/ which I wrote sometime back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrich Dangel points out in his comment above - the whole directory hierarchy leading to the required directory should be accessible to apache in order for it to serve the directory and its listing.

I had to chmod ~/bin/android-sdk-linux to 775 which was originally set to 770.